# Model Access throughout Entire Rails Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

*Ruby 1.9.3 + Rails 3.2.8*

I have a view that is rendered on every page in my app inside a partial:

```
<span id="sync-time">      
  <%= @sync.dropbox_last_sync.strftime('%b %e, %Y at %H:%M') %>
</span>
```

In order to use my `syncs` model and have access to the `dropbox_last_sync` method, I have to include it in **every controller** throughout my app. For example:

```
class EntriesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @sync = current_user.sync
  end
end
```

...

```
class CurrenciesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @sync = current_user.sync
  end
end
```

...etc.

**Is there a way I can make the** `syncs` **model available everywhere by including it in my Application Controller somehow?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to add a before_filter in your application controller:

```
before_filter :setup_sync

def setup_sync
  if current_user
    @sync = current_user.sync
  end
end
```

You need to be careful that your setup_sync filter runs after whatever code you are using to set up your current_user. This is probably another before_filter though so provided you have `before_filter :setup_sync` declared *after* your current user filter it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is better:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :authenciate_user!
  before_filter :index

  def index
    @sync = current_user.sync
  end
end
```

You're using `current_user` always, so you need to have `before_filter :authenciate_user!` here aswell and above the other one.